# MYSQL: Select rows with identical values in one column, and specific values in another

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table with the following pattern:

```
| customer_id | store_id | status_id |
|-------------|----------|-----------|
| 12345       | 12       | 5         |
| 12345       | 8        | 3         |
| 12345       | 6        | 8         |
| 14567       | 5        | 3         |
| 14567       | 5        | 6         |
| 16543       | 3        | 4         |
| 19876       | 3        | 5         |
| 19876       | 6        | 8         |
```

Say, I want to retrieve all rows...

- with identical customer IDs
- which in turn have different store IDs
- which all should have a status ID higher than 4

The correct output for the example table would therefore be:

```
| customer_id | store_id | status_id |
|-------------|----------|-----------|
| 19876       | 3        | 5         |
| 19876       | 6        | 8         |
```

Currently, I successfully wrote down a query to select all rows with an identical `customer_id`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE customer_id IN (
    SELECT customer_id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY customer_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

This query would pick me all rows with `customer_id = 12345` as well, but since one of the `status_id` of these rows is smaller than 4, I don't want this `customer_id`.

As an additional question, how would the final query look like when ported to Doctrine/Symfony?

Comment: I sense `... min(status_id) > 4` might help.

Comment: Where exactly would you put that statement in my query?

Comment: Where aggregation is done would be a good spot I presume.

Comment: so, something along the lines of `having count(*) > 1 and min(status_id) > 4`, I guess?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.*
    FROM (
        SELECT customer_id
            FROM tbl
            WHERE COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT STORE_id) -- no dup store_ids
            GROUP BY customer_id      -- per customer
            HAVING MIN(status_id) > 4 -- all status_id > 4
         ) AS a
    JOIN tbl AS b            -- go back to get other columns
        USING(customer_id);
```